# Make some parts of a script run in editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

So the problem is that I have one public variable in my script and when this variable is changed I want to call a specific function but only in **edit mode** and only when I am in **Unity Editor**. **ExecuteInEditMode** will make the **entire script** run in edit mode when I want **one little function**. Right now I use a separate script component with this code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class OtherScript: MonoBehaviour
{
    private ThatBigScript that_script;
    private float last_variable_value = 0.0f;

    void Update()
    {
        if(Application.isEditor && !EditorApplication.isPlaying)
        {
            if(that_script == null)
            {
                that_script = GetComponent<ThatBigScript >();
            }

            if(that_script.variable_to_check != last_variable_value )
            {
                that_script.FunctionToCall(that_script.variable_to_check );
                last_variable_value = that_script.variable_to_check ;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

It's a lot of work to create a whole separate component for one little function, so could someone please help me create something more beautiful and short?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This API will save your life: [MonoBehaviour.OnValidate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnValidate.html)

"This function is called when the script is loaded or a value is changed in the inspector (Called in the editor only)."